# How to make Highcharts fetch data from external JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Basically, I have this http://jsfiddle.net/TWF6N/

Instead of having the data series in the JS file, I want to have the JS retrieve a JSON file.

I do not want this to be in the JS file:

```
data = {"aaData": [
    [1, "70.1700", "2008-12-29 11:23:00"],
    [2, "70.2600", "2008-12-29 16:22:00"],
    [3, "70.6500", "2008-12-30 11:30:00"],
    [4, "70.8700", "2008-12-30 16:10:00"],
    [5, "70.5500", "2009-01-02 11:09:00"],
    [6, "70.6400", "2009-01-02 16:15:00"]
]};
```

How do I make this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Straight from [the HighChart documentation](http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocesssing-data-from-a-file):

Your JSON data would look like this:

```
[
    [1, "70.1700", "2008-12-29 11:23:00"],
    [2, "70.2600", "2008-12-29 16:22:00"],
    [3, "70.6500", "2008-12-30 11:30:00"],
    [4, "70.8700", "2008-12-30 16:10:00"],
    [5, "70.5500", "2009-01-02 11:09:00"],
    [6, "70.6400", "2009-01-02 16:15:00"]
]
```

And your JS would look something like this:

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(jsonData) {
        chartOptions.series = jsonData;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
    });

    var chartOptions = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        series: []
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're using some server side technology like php or asp.net?  If so, then you could just make a call back to the server to receive your json in a HttpResponse.